# How to enable db2 driver statement caching?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am aware that I can enable db2 driver's statement caching by adding a property in jdbcurl. But I did some research, I've got some properties:

[this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13753/db2.htm#JDBCD148)  said:

```
MaxPooledStatements
MaxStatements
```

[this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052607.html) said:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource.maxStatements
```

I've got confused, which one should I use? And is the property vary from a  version of the driver to another?

ps: My driver is db2jcc4-10.1.jar

Answer (score 1):

Your 1-st link is for *Oracle Type 4 JDBC DB2* driver, and the 2-nd one is for *IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ*.
These are different JDBC drivers.
According to your jar file name you use the 2-nd driver.